# SSIS E-mail Msg when rows get directed to OutputError

Tags: ssis

I have validation that happens and if it fails, it gets directed to "OutputError" column. Which eventually stores those rows in a table at the end to be reviewed/dealt with.

The plan is that this is not something that happens every time the package runs.

So I would like to send an e-mail to myself when a row(s) are sent to "OutputError". One e-mail for all rows.

OR it could trigger at the very last step, inserting the records into the error sql table, which is an OLE DB destination data flow task. If 1 or more rows is inserted using that OLE DEB destination, then send an e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Script Component to your Data Flow task, acting as a Transformation (default), before the OLE DB Destination that actually writes the error rows into the table.

The component will always "light up" so you'll want to implement a trivial row count in there or set a boolean flag that "yes, we've seen at least one row". This will be done by declaring a class level/member variable that you initialize in the `PreExecute` step.

In the ... I don't remember the name but something like `OnPipelineRowSent` increment the counter or set the flag to true. The actual count doesn't matter and yes, you could check whether the value is already true but it's a trivial operation so I wouldn't worry about the wasted cycles.

Then in the `PostExecute` method, you would check whether total row count > 0  or the "at least one row" flag is true. Then fire off your email activity.

Comment: Hi, so i've followed this logic. I've got a script component, it counts rows and as soon as a row is added it changes a boolean variable from false to true.

I am trying to in the event handling, use the OnVariableValueChanged method. But this event handler doesn't seem to be finding that boolean variable. I know the variable is triggering, i've gone into debug with breakpoints and confirmed it is changing its value.

I think (but have no idea) that maybe I haven't linked my event handler to the variable properly? I can't find information on how to do this though. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: There's no need to be using event handlers, much less OnVariableValueChanged. The PostExecute method in the Script Task is what you want. OnVariableValueChanged would only fire if you have created an SSIS scoped variable that you are updating in the Script Task, none of which I outlined. The SSIS framework Event Handler approach I find to be difficult to manage correctly

Comment: How about a rowcount object and then in the control flow use a test (rowCt>0) that leads to a send email?

Comment: So i'm finding a script example of sending an e-mail and they all have DTS. like this

`string v_From = Dts.Variables["User::vFrom"].Value.ToString();`

I can't figure out what Dts is, and if I change it to "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts" which is what it recommends, it comes back erroring and says the namespace doesn't exist. I can't find how to fix this.

Comment: The Dts.Variables notation is used in a `Script Task`. What I've been discussing is the `Script Component` which uses a different mechanism to interact with SSIS Variables as well as rules about when you can access/modify the values

Comment: @KeithL Feel free to throw that out as an approach. I feel like I'll be tapping out of this tip of the iceberg style question

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm missing something then. In my data flow. I brought over a script component object. Double click that script component object it says "Script transformation", from there I go edit script and in the "postExecute()" function I have this email code. 

So if that is correct, then that would mean the way i'm trying to send the e-mail using dts. is incorrect?

Comment: @billinkc Hi, Thank you for your help. I found the components you originally described and was able to put it together and get it working. It was a script task in the error handler to an e-mail component that finally got it working.